# database updation after google checkout payment

Tags: php, payment, google-checkout, sql-update

I am a new developer in php. In a website, I need to implement "Google checkout" payment method. My client give a script with `src`. I added that script into my website. I got a Google checkout page.

But I don't know how to customize the style of that page
and how to update my database, if the buyer pay the amount using Google checkout. Is there any option like PayPal `notify_url`? If yes, how to set up such url?

Comment: "I am a new developer" & "i need to implement Google checkout payment". What could possibly go wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You really have to show the code that is not working, the expected results and the error you have. You can always google for references otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can get order state notifications using the Checkout Notification API. Start with the doc below:

http://support.google.com/checkout/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134463

then read the full documentation for details:

https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API

Comment: Actualy i dont want order details.I have a project with many payment methods like PayPal,ACH etc.If someone pay the amount  through Google checkout,I need to get the value into a PHP file and and execute some php code.